# CSS multi-leveled class select

Tags: html, css

So my question is how to apply style only to `class="wp"` by id `#test`?
Because in my main project I have a lot of classes like `wp` but the id above is different from those classes so how to do it with id that the class inside `leaveit` will not be changed?

```css
#test {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  width: 550px;
  background: black;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="blablabla">
    <p class="wp">test</p>
    <p class="leaveit">This paragraph will be red and</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `#test .wp  {}` should do it.

Comment: jeeesus I just needed a space between id and class... thanks buddy

Comment: No problem. With no space it looks for an element with BOTH that id and class.

Answer (score 1):

```
#test .wp { /*styles go here*/ }
```

easy peasy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `#test` to target the element with the `test` id, the `.wp`
 to target the elements with `wp` class within the `#test` element.

Keep in mind that using `id` to target elements in CSS is considered as a bad practice as it's difficult to override it.

```css
#test .wp {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    width: 550px;
    background: black;
    height: 250px;
}
```